# Reactivityy vs events in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

I'm trying to create a clear picture of reactivity and what it means, vs events in javascript.

From Wikipedia :

```
// In computing, reactive programming is a programming paradigm orientated     
// around data flows and the propagation of change.
```

I struggling to distinguish how the actual implementation in javascript of an event driven UI might differ from a "reactive implementation" and would appreciate anyone able to contrast these patterns.

I've been using meteor for quite a while so understand it that context, but not its fundamental mechanics.

I assume that essentially it comes down to some sort of event or notification being published from a "reactive data source" or subject to another function, that is observing it, each being designed to "react" to these events.

Very specifically, how might the implementations differ from Publishingg and subscribing to events on a object that defines that object or the system it exists in as reactive?

Any help would be great.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming
- https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
- https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual

Comment: " how the actual implementation in javascript of an event driven UI might differ from a "reactive implementation" and would appreciate anyone able to contrast these patterns." Could you possibly elaborate on this a little? I get the feeling it's a little broad question? Don't know if others think this too.

Comment: Very specifically, how might the implementations differ from Publishingg and subscribing to events on a object that defines that object or the system it exists in as reactive?

Comment: Ok, I am no expert, by far, at reactive programming. But from what little I have seen, in reactive programming you can do the following: if you have a `var c = a + b` where `a = 1` and `b = 1`, its value, because of the way the language works at a very low level, is always bound to the values of `a` and `b`. So that if we were to do `b = 2` then `c`, automatically would now be equal to `3` without us doing something. Continues in next comment

Comment: In javascript, this is not the case. In Javascript when you do `var c = a + b` where `a = 1` and `b = 1` then `c` is simply a pointer to the primitive value `2` and that's it. If later you change `b = 2` `c` will still be pointing to `2`. Continues in next comment

Comment: In order to do something like the reactive example in javascript we need to use higher level constructs, that we create ourselves and are not part of the language, that somehow 'observe' things we are interested in, and when changes happen to them an appropriate event is fired, which is captured by anything listening for that event, allowing us to 'react' to it, however we see fit. I probably didn't help much, that's why I am writing in the comments and not posting an answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to show an example of  these higher level constructs? I'm trying to get past the seemingly impenetrable theory and excess of library specific uses that's discussed almost everywhere and find an example of an implementation that helps demonstrate its difference from an evented pub sub system.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that it's all about sequences over time, and being able to pass that representative object around, and work with it, while it provides methods for not only pass-through subscription, but also manipulation, transformation and collation.

If you were to think about an array `[1, 2, 3]`, and what you could do with it, without resorting to lower-level management of internals...

```
arr.map(add1).map(triple).filter(evens).reduce(add, 0);
// with a starting value of 0, add all numbers in arr,
// after they've had 1 added, been tripled,
// and had odd products stripped out
```

What if you could say:

```
div.mouseMoves
   .map(event => ({ x: event.x, y: event.y }))
   .filter(bottomHalfOfBox)
   .forEach(updateView);
```

Or do the same for `recentPosts` or `newsfeedUpdates` or `friendMessages`?

That's sort of the idea of it all, using streams, which are really rather arrays whose values are separated by time.

Every library has something different, different wrappers, different names for the same methods, different behaviours... but the goals are all similar.

And what you're seeing is that the callback aspect of the events is insufficient for this level of chained composition.

Some other languages have native (or syntax override) support for this type of feature, natively.
Javascript, not so much, of course.
Rather than relying on syntax, we need to rely on wrappers for this behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer, I totally understand there are many libraries, and they may well have different implementations.  What you seem to be demonstrating above is FRP,  I'm looking for the specifics of the implementation that may make a data source a reactive one, rather than how it might be used.

Comment: @pushplaybang so, specifically, a barebones JS implementation of an Observable, as taken from some/any asynchronous source (addEventListener, EventSource, setInterval, etc)? If that’s your ask, any preference for the concrete?

Comment: @pushplaybang The part that drove me to answer the way I did was "Very specifically, how might the implementations differ from Publishingg and subscribing to events on a object that defines that object or the system it exists in as reactive?" I assumed you meant "How might one connect to / use the Observable data-source", rather than "How might one implement an Observable data-source"

Comment: @pushplaybang the internal representation of a reactive Observable can still be seen as an array over time. If all you're interested in is the internal implementation, it would wrap whatever concrete event-listener type you had (eventListener, postMessage, xhr, et cetera), and offer a pub-sub on top. The key difference is the inversion, really. If Promises were about a stream, not a value, and the subscriber could tell the Promise when to stop sending updates, you'd have a reactive observable.

Comment: Very interesting thank you,  I'm definatelt still looking for a code example for a barebone js example, happy for any demonstration you would prefer, and thank you so far.

Answer (score 1):

Reactive systems usually mean reactive *streams*.

With pub/sub, A sends a message to B, and B may or may not do something with the message.

With reactive streams, A streams a message to B, and B provides *backpressure* to A, so A knows when its message has been received, and the stream has been *emptied*. There's also well defined semantics around *combining* streams, *duplexing* streams, etc. For comparison, with pub/sub, there are no such semantics, and the implementations for these operations are usually ill-defined and ad hoc. With well defined operations, *composing* and interoperating streams becomes easy.

Beyond the theoretical definition, different libraries do things in very different ways.

For a high level overview, I highly recommend https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor.